# Can't get XML (de)serializer to work

Tags: c#, xml, unity-game-engine, xml-parsing

I've been doing a quick challenge I set myself; make a generic XML (de)serializer. I'm having trouble with the I/O part of this. Code is as follows:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using UnityEngine;

public static class XML
{
    static readonly Dictionary<string, XmlSerializer> PathSerializers = new Dictionary<string, XmlSerializer>(); 

    public static T DeserializeXML<T>(string xmlPath)
    {
        var serializer = GetSerializer<T>(xmlPath);
        var xml = File.ReadAllText(GetFullPath(xmlPath));
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml)))
        {
            return (T) serializer.Deserialize(stream);
        }
    }

    public static void SerializeXML<T>(T obj, string xmlPath, bool append)
    {
        using (var text = new StreamWriter(GetFullPath(xmlPath), append, Encoding.ASCII))
        {
            GetSerializer<T>(xmlPath).Serialize(text, obj);
        }
    }

    private static XmlSerializer GetSerializer<T>(string relativePath)
    {
        return PathSerializers.ContainsKey(relativePath) ? PathSerializers[relativePath] : AddSerializer<T>(relativePath);
    }

    private static string GetFullPath(string relativePath)
    {
        return Path.Combine(Application.dataPath, relativePath);
    }

    private static XmlSerializer AddSerializer<T>(string relativePath)
    {
        if (File.Exists(GetFullPath(relativePath)))
        {
            File.Create(GetFullPath(relativePath));
        }

        if (PathSerializers.ContainsKey(relativePath))
        {
            Debug.Log("Loaded cached serializer");
            return GetSerializer<T>(relativePath);
        }

        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        PathSerializers.Add(relativePath, serializer);
        return serializer;
    }
}
```

It might be me doing some crazy rookie mistake, but I simply cannot see it.

The methods are called from another script, and called on a class that I know is set up correctly.

**Clarification:**

If I serialize and then deserialize the same data I get an error as follows:

> IOException: Sharing violation on path
>   C:\Dev\C#\Projects\XML\Assets\leaderboard.xml
>   System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, FileMode mode,
>   FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean
>   anonymous, FileOptions options) (at
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/FileStream.cs:320)
>   System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, FileMode mode,
>   FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize) (wrapper
>   remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.FileStream:.ctor
>   (string,System.IO.FileMode,System.IO.FileAccess,System.IO.FileShare,int)
>   System.IO.File.Create (System.String path, Int32 bufferSize) (at
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/File.cs:135)
>   System.IO.File.Create (System.String path) (at
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/File.cs:130)
>   XML.AddSerializer[Leaderboard] (System.String relativePath) (at
>   Assets/XMLLoader.cs:43) XML.GetSerializer[Leaderboard] (System.String
>   relativePath) (at Assets/XMLLoader.cs:31)
>   XML.SerializeXML[Leaderboard] (.Leaderboard obj, System.String
>   xmlPath, Boolean append) (at Assets/XMLLoader.cs:25) XMLTest.Start ()
>   (at Assets/XMLTest.cs:14)

Comment: Whats exactly your problem?

Comment: @Bgl86 I added a clarification.

Comment: Looks like the file is already opened by another application.

Comment: You could try adding a text.Close() in the SerializeXML to ensure the application closed the file after serializing

Comment: @Dbuggy It's the same error with the text.Close added. I've tried making a dummy file in place and the error persists indepedent of that. The only place it could be open is in the Unity Editor, and I REALLY hope the editor isn't that stupid.

**Edit** I tried building the project and the error persists.

Comment: There is no need to call close() within a using block.

Comment: I thought so too but in case it's not working better be sure it gets closed.

Comment: @Bgl86 Do you know what the problem is? I've looked at the code, walked through it with the debugger and built the  project. Through all that, the error seems to persist.

**Edit** Answer has been found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's a simple oversight. You are trying to create the file if it exists!. Just reverse the condition and it should be fine:

```
if (!File.Exists(GetFullPath(relativePath)))
{
    File.Create(GetFullPath(relativePath));
}
```

Comment: I now feel incredibly stupid. How could I not see that?

Answer (score 1):

For clarification this is what i use for serializing / deserializing xml with.

Perhaps with modifications it will help you.

```
/// <summary>
/// Class containing a load and store method to store a datafile as XML format.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The root object containing the data</typeparam>
public class DataFile<T> where T : new()
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Load the XML from Path
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="path">Path to a XML file containing the data for object of type T</param>
    /// <returns>An object of type T as represented by the XML. Will return default(T) when the </returns>
    public static T Load(string path)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(path)) return default(T);
        var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        using (var stream = File.OpenRead(path))
        {
            var reader = new XmlTextReader(stream);
            if (!ser.CanDeserialize(reader))
                return default(T); // return null indicating the file can not be loaded

            return (T) ser.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Stores an object of type T as XML into a file
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="path">A path to a file which should be written.</param>
    /// <param name="data">The object to be written to the given file</param>
    public static void Store(string path, T data)
    {
        var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        using (var stream = File.OpenWrite(path))
        {
            // Clear the file and write new contents.
            stream.SetLength(0);
            ser.Serialize(stream, data);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer definitely will help me rethink my programs in general. I overthink and make them way too bloated.